# Set onpress on createDrawerNavigator item in react native?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, stack-navigator, react-navigation-drawer

I have a drawer item "Share App" where I want to open an alert and display a message rather than opening an entire screen in react native. My code is as follows:

```
const Screen6_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  //All the screen from the Screen6 will be indexed here
  Sixth: {
    screen: ShareApp, //don't want this screen
    title:'Share',
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerLeft: () => <NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#138808',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
    }),
  },
});

const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator({
  ShareApp: {
    //Title
    screen: Screen6_StackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLabel: 'Share App',
      drawerIcon: (<Entypo name="share" size={20} color='black'></Entypo>)

    },
  },
);
```

Where Do I add the onPress parameter in order to call the function? I dont want the screen parameter, want a function to be called only when I click on Share App.

How to do that in react native??

Do help as I am new in React native development....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom drawer content component and pass it to the `contentComponent` option in the `DrawerNavigatorConfig`.

#### Creating the custom drawer content:

```
const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (
  <ScrollView>
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          // Do something...
          Alert.alert('Heading', 'Body');
        }}
        style={{ left: 15, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Entypo name="share" size={20} color='black'></Entypo>
        <Text style={{ marginLeft: 30, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Share App</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  </ScrollView>
);
```

The `DrawerItems` component will render clickable drawer options based on the screens you create, but above the `DrawerItems` we can add your share button for example.

#### Passing the custom drawer content component to `contentComponent`

```
const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Screen1: {
      // Properties...
    },
    // Other screens...
  },
  {
    // Pass custom drawer content component...
    contentComponent: props => <CustomDrawerContentComponent {...props} />,
    // Other configurations...
  },
);
```

*`DrawerItems`* should be imported from `react-navigation-drawer`.

Comment: Thanks this worked.. but not able to call a function on onPress of TouchableOpacity. How to do that?

Comment: Can you test by replacing the Alert line in my example by a normal `alert(1)` to check if it actually gets called? Because Alert doesn't work on `web`. So test on an actual device if you aren't already.

Comment: Yes..alert is coming proper but not able to call a function  onPress={() => this.testFunction()} , error shown is:  _this2.testFunction is not a function. (In '_this2.testFunction()', '_this2.testFunction' is undefined)

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah that's because `CustomDrawerContentComponent` is a functional component so you don't use `this`.